# Django: How to get User model's fields instead of select list in Employee form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on an application and I'm stuck in the very beginning. Please help me out here.

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

> **User** is from **django.contrib.auth.models**

**views.py**

```
class EmployeeCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Employee
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:view-employees')

def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.company = self.request.user.company
    self.object.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

**employee_form.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'core:add-employees' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="bnt btn-small">
</form>
```

**rendered html form**
[image]

## Here's the problem.

Instead of `User` being a **select list**, I want **fields** of User model, i.e. `username`, `email`, `password` etc, while the `Designation` should remain as the **select list**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ModelChoiceField` for the user field in your form. Creating a form class would make it rather easier.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield for reference.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to this. If you are only using `designation` field as an extra field to User. just adding `designation` to the User model will work easily.
to do this you can use multi-table inheritance as Following.

```
class Employee(User): # change Here
    # Remove -> user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

Now you will get what you wanted. but note that this will not best use case for many situations as it creates a left outer join in DB table.
but for this situation, I don't think it will affect anything.

to know more about Django multi-table inheritance see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

for other ways to extend user model see: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: I want to use django's User model for all auth etc purposes and Employee and Owner both have OneToField to User. Now, extending both with User model will serve my purpose?

Comment: by the above solution, it will! but it doesn't affect what method you use, as long as you are using AbstractBaseUser subclass, because all the auth procedure is done in it, and all the methods use it.